# Pole emploi refused my ARE benefits

Tags: immigration, france, employment, retirement-funds

I have been working for past few years in France. I have paid social security and taxes during that time. I did not have a problem when I was hired or paid taxes. When I applied for ARE, pôle emploi refused my request stating that I can not work in France. What should I do? I am afraid to apply for changing the status in my *titre de séjour* as I don't have job anymore. Can I claim my benefits some how?

Comment: Hello. Why does Pôle Emploi states that you cannot work in France ? What is your current status or titre de séjour ? Has your status changed since you lost (or quit ?) your job ? These informations might help to better understand your situation.

Comment: What kind of *titre de séjour* do you currently have? How did you leave your earlier job? That should be what decides whether you get ARE or not.

Comment: Hello. I have a talent passport titre de séjour mentioning projet économique innovant. I left my previous job after signing rupture conventionnelle. The status of the titre de sejour is not changed yet.